# Determinant Question.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that if $A=\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\c & d\end{bmatrix}$, then 
$\det(A)=\frac{1}{2}\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\tr(A^2) & (tr(A))^2\end{bmatrix}\right)$.

I tried finding the determinant using the formula but it didn't come out to be the same as when I found determinant using cofactor expansion.

Comment: It seems easy to verify. Can you show your calculations so that we can see what is eventually wrong?

Comment: I figured out where I went wrong, I expanded incorrectly, stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that 
$$det(A) = ad-bc$$
$$A^{2} = \begin{bmatrix} a^{2} + bc & ab + bd \\ ca + dc & cb + d^{2}\end{bmatrix}$$
Then 
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2} \cdot det(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\tr(A^2) & (tr(A))^2\end{bmatrix}) &=\frac{1}{2} \cdot det(\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\a^{2} + 2bc + d^{2} & (a+d)^{2}\end{bmatrix}) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}(a^{2} + 2ad + d^{2} - a^{2} - 2bc - d^{2}) \\
&= ad - bc 
\end{align*}
as required.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$
A^2=\begin{bmatrix}
a^2+bc & ab+bd \\
ca+dc & cb+d^2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
so $\operatorname{tr}(A^2)=a^2+2bc+d^2$. Thus the right-hand side is
$$
\frac{1}{2}((\operatorname{tr}(A))^2-\operatorname{tr}(A^2))=
\frac{1}{2}((a+d)^2-(a^2+2bc+d^2))=
\frac{1}{2}(2ad-2bc)=ad-bc
$$